# Which tool would be best analyzing human body movements and another persons reaction to it?

Tags: time-series, probability, modeling

I}m wanting to look at specific movements of body parts over time and see if person A responds to person B in a certain way everytime/most of the time/some of the time person B does something specific  ...

For example imagine something like boxing ... person B throws a certain kind of punch and then person A's response to is to move in a certain direction. I would look at what punch was thrown, which way did person A move to avoid it and what was a follow up response by either person.

The ultimate goal is to  make a model/decision-tree that shows how person A and person B react under certain movements .

I was thinking of maybe  time series but thought time may not be such a critical issue, as opposed to the actual sequence of events and reaction to the events which is of more interest.